# REBOL methods in Red

Tags: rebol, red

Disclaimer: What I'm trying to achieve is something like what was discussed here - [Evaluating a "variable variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394057/evaluating-a-variable-variable).

I want to create variables in red dynamically with identifiers based on some parsed data. Examples from post above mention Rebol (R2?) `rejoin` and `to-word` methods, but I didn't succeed calling them in Red however, getting `Script error: rejoin has no value` all the time.

Are such methods present in Red or what are the alternatives? Should I add some module into my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rebol, both `rejoin` and `to-word` are both shortcuts for more elemental functions. In Red (as of version 0.6.0) both of these functions are available:

```
>> to word! "foo"
== foo
>> to word! append "foo" "bar"
== foobar
```

It's likely better to copy the first string before appending, but this should be enough to create dynamic words.

Comment: Thanks for a help!

Comment: Note that REJOIN and TO-WORD are both now available in Red (at least since v0.6.3)